# Manhwa involving a blonde woman trying to help a blond boy who was having trouble with magic

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

Trying to find a manhwa story I saw an ad for on Instagram. I know it was a Tapas ad.

The little story mostly showed a little blond boy I think he had gold brown maybe red eyes and a woman who was also blonde and had gold brown eyes so I'm pretty sure they're related. The kid was having trouble with magic and the woman was trying to help him. I'm pretty sure the woman was reincarnated or something because the boy made it seem like the woman was mean or had no interest in him, but she seemed really kind. So I'm guessing it's one of those "a woman dies and is reincarnated as someone mean" stories.

I have tried really hard to find this story but to no avail so I'm hoping someone knows what this is.

Comment: Hi. How recently did you see the ad?

Comment: I believe it's possible to show the ads a company is running on their instagram profile page. I don't use IG so I can't check this personally. If you go to Tapas's page, do you see anything you recognize?